# Unable to parse single json object

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, getter-setter

I am trying to parse json but unable to get parse result.Always get null.Below is my whole json with single object.

```
{
    "posting_detail": {
        "posting_id": "14",
        "posting_title": "LuLu Last Offer",
        "posting_desc": "dqwewqewe",
        "mobile_number": "2344234234",
        "phone_number": "34234324",
        "address": "fefdsfds",
        "city_name": "Abu Dhabi",
        "created_on": "2015-06-22 14:55:05",
        "normal_price": null,
        "images": [
            {
                "photo_img": "xyz/images/posting/IMG_1212121219.jpg"
            },
            {
                "photo_img": "xyzm/images/posting/IMG_1212121220.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And here is the data set class.

```
package com.iptikarpromotion.vo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class PostingDetailVO implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("posting_id")
    private String posting_id;
    @SerializedName("posting_title")
    private String posting_title;
    @SerializedName("posting_desc")
    private String posting_desc;
    @SerializedName("mobile_number")
    private String mobile_number;
    @SerializedName("phone_number")
    private String phone_number;
    @SerializedName("address")
    private String address;
    @SerializedName("city_name")
    private String city_name;
    @SerializedName("created_on")
    private String created_on;
    @SerializedName("normal_price")
    private String normal_price;
    @SerializedName("images")
    private ArrayList<ImagesVO> images;


    public PostingDetailVO() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public PostingDetailVO(String posting_id, String posting_title, String posting_desc, String mobile_number, String phone_number, String address, String city_name, String created_on) {

        this.posting_id = posting_id;
        this.posting_title = posting_title;
        this.posting_desc = posting_desc;
        this.mobile_number = mobile_number;
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
        this.address = address;
        this.city_name = city_name;
        this.created_on = created_on;

    }

    public String getPosting_id() {
        return posting_id;
    }

    public void setPosting_id(String posting_id) {
        this.posting_id = posting_id;
    }

    public String getPosting_title() {
        return posting_title;
    }

    public void setPosting_title(String posting_title) {
        this.posting_title = posting_title;
    }

    public String getPosting_desc() {
        return posting_desc;
    }

    public void setPosting_desc(String posting_desc) {
        this.posting_desc = posting_desc;
    }

    public String getMobile_number() {
        return mobile_number;
    }

    public void setMobile_number(String mobile_number) {
        this.mobile_number = mobile_number;
    }

    public String getPhone_number() {
        return phone_number;
    }

    public void setPhone_number(String phone_number) {
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity_name() {
        return city_name;
    }

    public void setCity_name(String city_name) {
        this.city_name = city_name;
    }

    public String getCreated_on() {
        return created_on;
    }

    public void setCreated_on(String created_on) {
        this.created_on = created_on;
    }

    public String getNormal_price() {
        return normal_price;
    }

    public void setNormal_price(String normal_price) {
        this.normal_price = normal_price;
    }

    public ArrayList<ImagesVO> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(ArrayList<ImagesVO> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

}
```

Other images data set class

```
public class ImagesVO implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("photo_img")
    private String photo_img;

    public String getPhoto_img() {
        return photo_img;
    }

    public void setPhoto_img(String photo_img) {
        this.photo_img = photo_img;
    }
}
```

And here is the parser method. Nothing wrong with the response. but only problem is unable to parse the whole json.

```
 public static PostingDetailVO getPostingDetail(String response){

      PostingDetailVO postingDetailVO = new PostingDetailVO();

      if (response !=null) {

          try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

            if (jsonObject !=null && jsonObject.has(KEY_POSTING_DETAIL)) {

                GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();

                Gson gson = builder.create();

                postingDetailVO = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), PostingDetailVO.class);

                Log.e("", "WORKING BOY==" + postingDetailVO.getPhone_number());

               }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return postingDetailVO;

    }


}
```

Comment: are you getting null response from server ?

Comment: Here i am getting null. at that point.                                       postingDetailVO = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), PostingDetailVO.class);                    

                Log.e("", "WORKING BOY==" + postingDetailVO.getPhone_number());

Comment: jsonObject.toString() is good. But PostingDetailVO.class); give me null in the log Log.e("", "WORKING BOY==" + postingDetailVO.getPhone_number());

Comment: means you are getting jsonObject null. So use Rest Client to check are you passing and getting paramateres ok ?

Comment: You have `posting_detail` as main object under it all fields coming so you have to make another class which have `PostingDetailVO` class object declared only.

Comment: This is my response on line.   gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString().                                               {"posting_detail":{"posting_id":"14","posting_title":"LuLu Last Offer","posting_desc":"dqwewqewe","mobile_number":"2344234234","phone_number":"34234324","address":"fefdsfds","city_name":"Abu Dhabi","created_on":"2015-06-22 14:55:05","normal_price":null,"images":[{"photo_img":"http:\/\/ivv\/images\/posting\/IMG_1212121219.jpg"},{"photo_img":"http:\/\/vv\/images\/posting\/IMG_1212121220.jpg"}]}}

Comment: What do you means i am just getting simple result from server and than parse that json, no posting the detail on server means no post request. Only GET request here i am using. my response is ok. but the problem is unable to parse the response.

Comment: I think my problem is in the data set class can any body please set my data set classes. and than i use .

Answer (score 0):

Just make another class as name `PostingDetail`

```
public class PostingDetail implements Serializable{

 PostingDetailVO objectPostingDetailVO; 

}
```

and then instead of

```
postingDetailVO = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), PostingDetailVO.class);
```

Use this:

```
PostingDetail objPostingDetail = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), PostingDetail.class);
```

Comment: i am getting still null. in the                                                                log.postingDetail = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), PostingDetailVO.class);
Log.e("", "WORKING BOY==" + postingDetail.getObjectPostingDetailVO().getAddress());

Comment: i can give you url and you can try. can i give you?

Comment: HI                                                                                                                                    I solve my last solution. but here i facing an other issue with array converting to string. can any body help me.                                                         private ArrayList<ImagesVO> bannerGalleryId;                                             bannerGalleryId = (ArrayList<ImagesVO>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("bannerIdForGallery");                         but i want to convert thisarray list to string arraylistfor galleryview.